# Fill custom area with color

Tags: delphi, colors, delphi-7, paint, fill

How can I fill a selected area with color?

```
var Rect: TRect;
    Color: TColor;
begin
  //fill area with color
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have not stated what you mean by *custom area* and you talk about a "selected area". I don't know what you mean.

For a simple rectangle then you typically would fill the rectangle with `TCanvas.FillRect`.

```
Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
Canvas.FillRect(R);
```

where `R` is a `TRect` specifying the rectangle.

For a more complex region then you need to fall back on the Windows GDI function [`FillRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162720%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). This function is not wrapped by `TCanvas` but you can simply call it passing `TCanvas.Handle` as the `HDC`.

Comment: And just to add, for non-rectangular area I'd suggest `ExtFloodFill` function

Comment: @Magicmaster I didn't think of that. It's a good suggestion though. Flood fill is a bit different from FillRect/FillRgn but could be appropriate here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to be a LOT more specific, but this should get you going in the right direction:

```
procedure DoMyDrawing(Canvas: TCanvas; L, T, R, B: Integer; Color: TColor);
var
  Rec: TRect;
begin
  Rec.Left:= L;
  Rec.Top:= T;
  Rec.Right:= R;
  Rec.Bottom:= B;
  //SAME AS Rec:= Rect(L, T, R, B);
  Canvas.Brush.Color:= Color;
  Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
  Canvas.FillRect(Rec);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DoMyDrawing(Self.Canvas, 10, 10, 50, 50, clNavy);
end;
```

---

**EDIT:**

I would more-so recommend using a TRect instead of the 4 coordinates (Left, Top, Right, and Bottom) because a TRect includes all 4 of those already. You can also read a TRect with a TopLeft TPoint and a BottomRight TPoint.

(I also fixed a typo above - `Canvas.FillRect(R);` was supposed to be `Canvas.FillRect(Rec);`)

Here's another version of the same procedure:

```
procedure DoMyDrawing(Canvas: TCanvas; const R: TRect; const Color: TColor);
begin
  Canvas.Brush.Color:= Color;
  Canvas.Brush.Style:= bsSolid;
  Canvas.Pen.Style:= psClear;
  Canvas.FillRect(R);
end;
```

Much easier, isn't it?

---

**ANOTHER EDIT:**

Also note the function I'm using `Rect(Left, Top, Right, Bottom)` - This makes things simple too. Unfortunately I've seen some standard VCL controls which have events with parameters named `Rect: TRect;` which messes up the ability to use the original function in the `classes` unit. So also avoid using a variable with the name `Rect` because it will prevent you from being able to use the `Rect` function (which turns 4 lines of code into just 1).

Comment: I also recommend instead of using 4 numbers (Left, Top, Right, Bottom), use TRect instead, which is all 4 already combined together.

Comment: Rather than commenting on your own answer, you can just edit it. It's a wiki. In fact anyone can edit your answer.